# Yii2 - Gridview sorting using a model attribute

Tags: php, gridview, yii

In my model, i have tableName set to a database. I created a new attribute in the model called $fullname and defined it by joining with another table/model in my afterFind function like so:

```
public function afterFind()
{
    parent::afterFind();

    $temp = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("select last_name || ', ' || first_name as fullname from employees where EMP_ID = :emp_id");
    $temp->bindValues([':emp_id' => $this->EMP_ID]);
    $this->fullname = $temp->queryColumn()[0];
}
```

I am trying to figure out how I can use this model attribute in my gridview to sort by this fullname attribute.

I have tried

```
 $dataProvider->setSort([
    'attributes' => [
        'fullname' => [
            'asc' => ['fullname' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['fullname' => SORT_DESC],
            'label' => 'Full Name',
            'default' => SORT_ASC
        ]
    ]
    ]);
```

Can anyone tell me how I can sort by this attribute or an alternative to this solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['fullname'] = [
    'asc' => ['first_name' => SORT_ASC, 'last_name' => SORT_ASC],
    'desc' => ['first_name' => SORT_DESC, 'last_name' => SORT_DESC],
    'default' => SORT_ASC
];
```